# PSQL trying to connect to wrong database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have noticed recently a weird (at least to me) behaviour of `psql` when trying to run `psql -l`. The essential steps to reproduce it are:

1. Create a sample DB (I did it with docker and created a simple role with a password)
2. Export environment variables that are used by `psql`

   ```
   PGPASSWORD=password
   PGDATABASE=database
   PGUSER=username
   ```
3. Edit the `pg_hba.conf`. And instead of having the default for `local` I replaced it with. Of course don't forget about reloading the configuration.

   ```
   local   database          username                                  trust
   ```
4. Running `psql` works as expected but running `psql -l` results in

   ```
   psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "username", database "database", SSL off
   ```

This seems to not take the environment variables into account when making a connection to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

The man page for psql says (emphasis mine):

> -l
>
> --list
>
> List all available databases, then exit. Other non-connection options are ignored. This is similar to the meta-command \list.
>
> When this option is used, psql will connect to the database postgres,
>   unless a different database is named on the command line (option -d or
>   non-option argument, possibly via a service entry, *but not via an
>   environment variable*).

Comment: Thanks! Anyway it is really confusing to me why all the environment variables are used like `PGPASSWORD` etc. but this one is omitted.